# Can I set custom ad banner sizes for Portrait iPhone/iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, admob, iad

iAd and AdMob's banner sizes only perfectly fit iPhone 4's and 5's. However, according to storyboards size, at least in terms of width, the perfect width size for iPhone 6 for a banner = 375. For iPhone 6+ perfect width for banner = 415. On Admob site for banner sizes, there is no supported width size 375 or 415. Even if I add Admob's Smartbanner code, it still doesn't have the 375, 415 sizes for the iPhone6, 6+ width. Same thing goes for iAd. What do i do then? Can I just make the custom size? I tested with test ads with these custom sizes and simulator and device work fine with them. However, will Apple accept this? Or is there another way to make ad banners fit full width size of phone?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could give you a definite answer as to what Apple would do, but I can tell you the iAds in my apps in the App Store work fine at multiple widths in the different iPhones.

Comment: What you mean by multiple widths? Do you mean you custom sized the widths to fit your storyboards or xib or whatever you use?

Comment: My apps on the AppStore were last compiled under iOS 7, and they scale for iPhone 4s, 5, 5s, 6 and 6 Plus running iOS 8 fine.  When you create an app in iOS 8, you can get the iAd BannerView to scale by using Constraints in AutoLayout.  You can find AutoLayout video tutorials in the WWDC videos, YouTube and there are several on Ray Wenderlich's site.  There may be other ways to do it, but I mostly use StoryBoards with AutoLayout now.